# Azure VM. Get OS version. Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, operating-system

I'm trying to do a powershell script that can list my VM's in Azure, including what OS they are.
I managed to get a list of my VM's using:

```
Get-AzureVM
```

But I can't find the OS version.

I also know about asking the WMI:

```
(Get-WmiObject -class Win32_OperatingSystem).Caption
```

But that's not going to work with the VM's I have in DMZ, as I have no network connection to them from where I'm runing the script.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For the new compute:

```
$json = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <resource group name>-ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -ApiVersion 2015-11-01
```

which returns a JSON blob, which you can query, e.g.:

```
$json.properties.storageProfile.imageReference
```

would be something like:

```
      "imageReference": {
        "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
        "offer": "WindowsServer",
        "sku": "2012-R2-Datacenter",
        "version": "latest"
      },
```

For ClassicCompute:
You can't get the OS version but you can inspect the source image name which should give you a string from which you can infer the OS version.

```
$json = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName <resource group name> -ResourceType Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines -ApiVersion 2015-11-01
```

Which returns a JSON blob, where you get the source image name:

```
$json.properties.storageProfile.operatingSystemDisk.sourceImageName
```

e.g. b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-14_04_2-LTS-amd64-server-20150506-en-us-30GB

Answer (score 0):

Find-AzureRmResource is no longer available.
Instead, Get-AzureRmResource seems to have taken its place.
But, the command like below does not give OS version details

$json = Get-AzureRmResource  -ResourceType Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines -ApiVersion 2020-06-01
echo $json

Name              : mymachine
ResourceGroupName : myresourcegroup
ResourceType      : Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines
Location          : eastus
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/abcdefg-1234-5678-ffff-e8219072/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myresourcegroup
Tags              :